# Get new access token from json object c# weatherbug api

Tags: java, c#, json, api, parsing

I want to call the url, Call Format:  [https://thepulseapi.earthnetworks.com/oauth20/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=(Consumer](https://thepulseapi.earthnetworks.com/oauth20/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%28Consumer) Key)&client_secret=(Consumer Secret Key)

which gives a json object like

```
{
    "OAuth20": {
        "access_token": {
            "token": "YwLFnMnyGYoyGGkddWtsbTUR8IZA",
            "refresh_token": "YwLFnMnyGYoyGGkddWtsbTUR8IZA",
            "token_type": "bearer",
            "expires_in": 86399
        }
    }
}
```

The token refreshes every session or when it expires, so i need to create a way to get this to pass through each time with out hard coding it. Any examples or suggestions on this weather bug api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend [Json.net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Using it is quite easy to use.

```
JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(YourJsonResponse);
var token = jObject.SelectToken("OAuth20").SelectToken("access_token");
```

If you want to generate a class for it you can also use [Json2cSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: I did Jobject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(myurl); Is that ok? The first Jobject says i need a reference for it.

Comment: I did a  WebClient client = new WebClient();string jsonURL="url"; var source = client.downloadstring(jsonURL) THEN the code above. Thanks.